# Denying own statement

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a word of phrase for someone who denies their own statement?

It’s like when somebody snitches and then denies having done so.

Comment: Besides "liar", right? That's a good question.

Comment: He'd probably call himself "a victim of misquotation."

Comment: _double-crosser_?

Comment: why specifically Canadian English? Do you have reason to believe Canadians use a different word for this than other English-speaking people?

Answer (score 3):

**Recanter** noun (formal) a person who makes a repudiation or withdrawal of a former belief or statement, esp formally in public [(Collins English Dictionary)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/recanter)

from *recant* (v.) 1530s, from Latin recantare "recall, revoke," from re- "back" (see re-) + cantare "to chant" (see chant (v.)). A word from the Reformation. Loan-translation of Greek palinoidein "recant," from palin "back" + oeidein "to sing." [(Online Etymology Dictionary)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=recant&searchmode=none)

Comment: But would that not be a deliberate and public retraction, rather than underhand denial as implied by the question? _Recanter_ sounds too honourable for that.

Comment: @OliverMason no, recanting just means that they recanted. It can be a deeply dishonourable thing to do, depending on just what was recanted and why.

Answer (score 0):

In legal parlance, a witness can sometimes ***turn** hostile* or *contradict* himself.